# Changes in PostgreSQL Database Not Reflected on Local Server

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I set up a Postgres database on my localhost, and then used python psycopg2 to login and add a bunch of files.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="testdb", user="user", password="*****", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

When I use the cursor to query the database, I find that my changes have been added, but when I login to my database via psql, I find that none of the changes have been made.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM articletable;')  
x = cursor.fetchall()
print x
```

Is there a special command to commit the changes made by cursor.execute()? I have looked on the psycopg2 documentation, and the latest version has removed the cursor.commit() call.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! cursor.commit() does not exist, but connection.commit() does. 
Use connection.commit() to commit changes.